# error in recursively finding subset sum java

Tags: java, recursion

I get a recursion error when this runs. And the parameters should not be changed

n is the size of a subset that contains the sum (goal) needed:
so

```
set[] = {5,6,9,-1,4,2}
n = 3
sum = 10
```

would equate to true because of the subset of size 3 that sums to 10 is {9,-1,2}

```
public static boolean isSubsetSum(int[] set, int n, int sum) {
int[] copy = new int[set.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(set, 0, copy, 0, set.length - 1);

// Base Cases
  if (sum == 0 && n == 0)
    return true;
  if (set.length == 0)       // fixed base case. 
    return false;

  if (set[set.length - 1] > sum) {
    return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum);
  }

  return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum) || isSubsetSum(copy, n-1, sum - set[set.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that when you call

```
return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum)
```

`n` and `sum` are not decremented so they will never reach zero. You do have a call at the end where `n` and `sum` are changed, but from reading the code it is clear that for some function inputs you will never get there.

Comment: I've experienced this with the subset {-4,0,4}, n = 2 (or 3), and sum needing to be 0... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The recursion error you are seeing is (at least partly) because of the left hand side of your return statement.

`copy` is an exact duplicate of set, so calling `isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum)` is the same as calling `isSubsetSum(set, n, sum)`. If one of your base cases does not apply to set, it will also not apply to copy, resulting in infinite recursions on the left half of the `||` evaluation (which is evaluated first).  Thus, the program will never find a solution to the question, and eventually you'll hopefully see that recursion error (or it will just keep chugging forever!)

To avoid this, you'll want to modify your recursive call in the return statement to only deal a subset of the problem.

Comment: Which return statement? and how would you recommend decrementing it?

Comment: I was referring to the final return statement: `return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum) || isSubsetSum(copy, n-1, sum - set[set.length-1]);`.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your code, I saw you get this error: `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`, and you get that because when your array size is 0, you try to copy it with length -1 at the 2nd line of your method. 
Change the order of the lines (check this base case at the beginning), and your method will work fine.